# Invalid use of group function - 1111, sum case

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
      a.emp_id
    , s.name
    , s.department
    ,sum(  case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, min(a.punchtime), max(a.punchtime))< 4  then 1 else 0 end  ) as 'Half Day'

FROM time_dimension c
LEFT JOIN machinedata a ON c.db_date = a.punchdate
LEFT JOIN emp s ON a.emp_id = s.emp_id
WHERE month(c.db_date) = 11 

GROUP BY
      a.emp_id
    , s.name
    , s.department
ORDER BY `s`.`department` ASC, s.name asc
```

I get #1111 - Invalid use of group function if i use the above code. But if i remove min and max in sum case the code runs but gives a wrong sum.

How can I use Min and Max in Sum Case?

Comment: It's illegal and nonsensical to nest aggregate functions. Please explain what you're trying to do first.

Comment: I am trying to count  emp_id's   punchtime is less than 4 hours for the selected month.

Comment: What's the sum for?