# TIMESTAMPDIFF Sum Case error

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| punchtime | punchdate | emp_id |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 9:51:00   | 4/1/2016  |      2 |
| 12:59:00  | 4/1/2016  |      2 |
| 10:28:00  | 4/1/2016  |      5 |
| 14:13:00  | 4/1/2016  |      5 |
| 9:56:00   | 4/1/2016  |     10 |
| 15:31:00  | 4/1/2016  |     10 |
| 10:08:00  | 5/1/2016  |      2 |
| 18:09:00  | 5/1/2016  |      2 |
| 10:15:00  | 5/1/2016  |      5 |
| 18:32:00  | 5/1/2016  |      5 |
| 10:11:00  | 6/1/2016  |      2 |
| 18:11:00  | 6/1/2016  |      2 |
| 10:25:00  | 6/1/2016  |      5 |
| 18:28:00  | 6/1/2016  |      5 |
| 10:19:00  | 6/1/2016  |     10 |
| 18:26:00  | 6/1/2016  |     10 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

I need to count where emp_id punchtime is less then that 4 hours and count ir for the whole. i am trying the below code but its not working.

```
SELECT
  a.emp_id,
  sum(  case when TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, min(a.punchtime),
  max(a.punchtime))< 4  then 1 else 0 end  ) as 'Half Day'
FROM  machinedata a
GROUP BY
  a.emp_id
```

I am getting a error #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Desired output -

```
+-----------+-----------+
| emp_id    | Half Day  | 
+-----------+-----------+
|2          | 1         |
|8          | 0         | 
|10         |0          | 
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: What you're doing is odd. Since you're timestampdiff'ing on aggregated values already (min/max), there will be only one `case when` to be computed per emp_id, therefore your sum is useless. The expected result suggests `half day` should be either 1 or 0, correct?

Comment: What is the datatype of `punchdate` and `punchtime` ?

Comment: "2 8 10" is a nonsensical output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid use of group function - 1111, sum case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273731/invalid-use-of-group-function-1111-sum-case)

Comment: Let me say this again: your query fails **because it makes no sense**. If you want us to help you with an alternative, you'll need to do a much better job at explaining your requirements.

Comment: sebas, i need to count how many half days the employee has taken for the entire month.

Comment: Strawberry, those are employee ids created by the punch machine. the missing ids were deleted by the admin from the punch machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your data set and desired result do not accord, so I'm going to ignore it...

Instead consider the following...

Note both the way in which I have presented the problem, and the construction of the solution.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(employee_id INT NOT NULL
,punchtime DATETIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(employee_id,punchtime)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 2,'2016/01/04 09:51:00'),
( 2,'2016/01/04 12:59:00'),
( 5,'2016/01/04 10:28:00'),
( 5,'2016/01/04 14:13:00'),
(10,'2016/01/04 09:56:00'),
(10,'2016/01/04 15:31:00'),
( 2,'2016/01/05 10:08:00'),
( 2,'2016/01/05 18:09:00'),
( 5,'2016/01/05 10:15:00'),
( 5,'2016/01/05 18:32:00'),
( 2,'2016/01/06 10:11:00'),
( 2,'2016/01/06 18:11:00'),
( 5,'2016/01/06 10:25:00'),
( 5,'2016/01/06 18:28:00'),
(10,'2016/01/06 10:19:00'),
(10,'2016/01/06 18:26:00');

SELECT employee_id
     , SUM(diff < 14400 ) half
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
             , DATE(x.punchtime) dt
             , TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(y.punchtime)) - TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(x.punchtime)) diff
          FROM my_table x 
          JOIN my_table y 
            ON y.employee_id = x.employee_id
           AND DATE(y.punchtime) = DATE(x.punchtime)
         GROUP
            BY x.employee_id
             , dt
      ) n
  GROUP
     BY employee_id;
+-------------+------+
| employee_id | half |
+-------------+------+
|           2 |    1 |
|           5 |    1 |
|          10 |    0 |
+-------------+------+
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the join. Also, I suspect OP wants to sum the time elapsed between alternating in/out punches. E.g. 1:00,2:00,4:30,5:30 is 2 hours.

Comment: yes. and it needs to be counted for the entire month.